# RegEx to parse custom tags

Tags: c#, regex

I would like to parse following input.

```
{*HEADER}
Product
{*DESCRIPTION}
Product Name

{*HEADER}
Service
{*DESCRIPTION}
Service Name
```

and the output should be something like .

```
List<Dictionary <string,string> >
key = HEADER , value = Product
Key = DESCRIPTION , value = Product Name
```

and same for the next object of list.

Comment: Do you mean "custom" tags which might say some fixed ones of interest or is it really "costume" to dress thes up - I do not understand. It would help to tailor regular expressions. And what coding language to drive the regex machinery and produce the wanted output? The tag "c#" in this case to me, might also indicate only, that you generate c# code, not how you do it (I mean with what language) could also be Python?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My idea of parsing your input would be the use of [negated class](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html#negated) and [capturing groups](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html).

```
{\*([^}]+)}\s*([^{]*[^\s{])
```

- `[{\*([^}]+)}` will capture the *key* to `$1`
- `\s*` followed by any amount of whitespace
- `([^{]*[^\s{])` captures the *value* to `$2` not ending in a whitespace (right trimmed).

[Here is a demo at regexstorm](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%7b%5c*(%5b%5e%7d%5d%2b)%7d%5cs*(%5b%5e%7b%5d*%5b%5e%5cs%7b%5d)&i=%7b*HEADER%7d%0d%0aProduct%0d%0a%7b*DESCRIPTION%7d%0d%0aProduct+Name%0d%0a%7b*HEADER%7d%0d%0aService%0d%0a%7b*DESCRIPTION%7d%0d%0aService+Name)

Comment: Regex r = new Regex(@"({\*(?<key>[^}]+)}\s*)(?<value>[^}{]*[^\s}{])");